# If $P$ is the power set of the set $A = \{ x : x^2-x-2=0 \}$, then find $n(P)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If $P$ is the power set of the set $A= \{ x:x^2-x-2=0 \}$, then find $n(P)$.

My attempt:

$$x^2-x-2=0$$
$$x^2-2x+x-2=0$$
$$x(x-2)+1(x-2)=0$$
$$(x-2)(x+1)=0$$

How do I proceed further?

Comment: Well, first you compute the set $A$ from the calculation you gave. Then you compute the power set $P$, then you compute $n(P)$ (whatever that stands for...).

Comment: $P=\{\emptyset, \{-1\}, \{2\}, \{-1,2\}\}$.

Comment: In general, the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of a set $A$ with $n$ elements has $2^n$ elements.

Comment: So, how many elements has the set of roots of a [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, What does this mean " So, how many elements has the set of roots of a quadratic equation ?"?

Comment: The set $A$ of your question is defined of the set of $x$ that satisfy the equation...

Comment: Thus, as by Peyton's comment: $-1,2 \in A$.

Comment: I assume that $n(P)$ is the number of elements of the power set of $A$: $P=\mathcal P(A)$.

Comment: If not so, please explain...

Comment: @MauriALLEGRANZA, Yes. $n(P)$ is the number of elements in set P

Comment: So, you have all that you need: *(i)* the rule for finding the roots of a quadratic equation; *(ii)* the def of *power set*; *(iii)* the rule for computing the number of elements of the power set of a finite set.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, could you provide me step by step solution. I'm quite confused.

Comment: @blue_eyed_...: What are you confused about? Mauro is practically giving you the solution on a silver platter. Frankly, currently it looks like your strategy is that you have decided _not to read anything_ people write to you and just repeat "I'm confused" like a broken record until they provide you with a homework solution you can type out and hand in without having to understand anything yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to start reading the definition of the set $A = \{ \ x \mid x^2−x−2=0 \ \}$.

It is the set of *roots* of the [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation): $x^2−x−2=0$.

You have rewritten the equation as: $(x−2)(x+1)=0$ and thus its roots are: $-1$ and $2$ (see also comment above), that means:

> $A = \{ -1, 2 \}$.

Now we have to "build" the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) $P=\mathcal P(A)$ (see comment above).

We know that, for a finite set with $n$ elements, its power set has $2^n$ elements.

We know that $A$ has two elements, i.e. $n(A)=2$, and thus we may conclude that:

> $n(P)=4$.

Answer (score 1):

The discriminant of $x^2-x-2$ is $1^2-4(-2)>0$. Hence the equation $x^2-x-2=0$ has two solutions.

$$n(P)=2^{n(A)}=2^2=4$$